# The "username" field below is not populating in my Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to create an image gallery for a social networking site that I am working on for a college project but I can't seem to get the "username" field to populate in my database. The galleryimage field populates fine, but the username field just displays "0". I have 3 fields in my "gallery" table (id, username, and galleryimage). I'm using MVC with CodeIgniter framework. Seems to be a problem with my Active Record code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the get/set functions in my model:

```
        private $galleryTable = 'gallery';

          function Gallery()
          {
            parent::__construct();
          }
```

The putProfileGallery populates the gallery table in my database.

```
         function putProfileGallery($username, $image)
          {
            $record = array('username' => $username, 'galleryimage' => $image);

            $this->db->where('username', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);
          }
```

The getProfileGallery function loops through the table and is supposed to output to the screen.

```
         function getProfileGallery($username)

          {
            $this->db->select('*')->from('gallery')->where('username', $username);
            $gallerySet = $this->db->get();

            $gallery = array();
            foreach ($gallerySet->result() as $row)
            {       
                $gallery[] = array('username' => $row->username, 'galleryimage' => $row->galleryimage);
            }
            return $gallery;
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine `where` and `insert`.

`$this->db->where('username', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);` should be only `$this->db->insert('gallery', $record);`

You should use `update` if you want to update a row.

Comment: Hi Shomz, I have removed the where() but still not having any luck, any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, what does `echo $this->db->last_query();` output if you put it right below the insert part?

Comment: Hi Shomz, it outputs:  INSERT INTO `gallery` (`user`, `galleryimage`) VALUES (0, 'http://localhost:8080/ci/spacebook2/assets/images/thumbnails/lisasax167.gif')

Comment: Hi, then there's a problem right where you're calling the `putProfileGallery` function - check what is the first parameter you're sending. You haven't shown that part of the code.

Comment: Hi, this is where I'm calling the function in the controller: $username = $this->session->userdata('galleryimage');
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    $filename=$image_data['file_name'];   
    $this->gallery->putProfileGallery($username, base_url()."spacebook2/assets/images/thumbnails/".$filename);
    redirect('mygallery');

Comment: Got it - just needed to change "$this->session->userdata('galleryimage')" to $this->session->userdata('username')  --> thanks a million for your help - happy xmas :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help! Enjoy your holidays :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this before you invoke the insert function, in order to make sure that $username has a correct value

```
var_dump ($username);
```

Besides that, I see that you have a where() before insert(), which does not seem correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response tomor, I removed the where() and ran the var dump - it threw up: string(4) "Bart" (Bart being the user loggged in) still no joy :( --> any suggestions? cheers!

Comment: @imac23 What datatype is "name" in your table?

Comment: Hi Damien, it's a VARCHAR - it has populated in the past, but doesn't want to work for me for now...